# Outlook : to detect incoming email of many accounts, how get rid of of the search folder itself (not only the old searches virtual folders)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search-folder

I have several accounts and wish to see when a new email arrives. For that, I need to reduce the number of lines with email folders to see more accounts. Therefore I wish I could get rid of the "Search Folder" Outlook imposed at some point. I looked in the options settings with no success. I tried right click in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of search folders being impossible, I used bookmarks of the inbox folders of the ten or so accounts at the top of the left column. Then, with those lines added, I can see when an email arrives and even click on the bookmark to access the inbox quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Glad to see that you have found the solution that suits you. By the way, in order to close this thread normally, please kindly accept helpful replies or your own reply as answers. Thanks for your understanding and support.

Comment: Thank for your kind concern - I was waiting for the delay to accept one's own answer to come to an end

Answer (score 1):

Removing or disabling the Outlook search folder feature is not an available option. In order to get notified more obviously when receiving new emails, enable desktop alert feature or display specific messages in New Item Alert windows using Outlook rules should be able to help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good idea, but I don't want to be disturbed "real time". I will use it for very specific types of email.